# Chef-(server): What is the difference between client and user

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have installed open-source chef-server (11.x). I am a newbie with chef. I can see that there are `user`s with passwords and pub/priv keys (usually the knife users (@workstations)). There are also `client`s (chef-validator, nodes...) with pub/priv keys.

When I do `knife configuration --initial` it uses `admin` username and priv key to crate new workstation user for example `johnnym`. So admin user with key is powerful enough to create user,node,client,...etc.

But when I `knife bootstrap ${FQDN}` it requires a `client` with admin privileges (chef-validator) to be able to authn/authz to the chef-server and register new node/client.

**My question is: Why do we separate client and user if they can accomplish the same tasks?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the context of OSS Chef as is your case, a `user` also works as a `client`, with the added ability to use the Web UI via username/password combination.

What you're missing is the [`validator`](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/auth.html#chef-validator) client key.

The `validator` is a special client that has one purpose only: to allow nodes to register themselves as clients on the Chef server. It's used from inside the node on the first Chef run. Once the node is registered, it's good practice to delete the `validator` key from the node.

When you run `knife bootstrap` it copies the key from your workstation to the node via SSH prior to running `chef-client`. The problem you're facing is probably either because you don't have the `validator` key on the workstation, or because `knife` is unable to find it (check your `knife.rb` file to see where it expects to find the key).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The good thing is that I have no problem...everything is working. I just don't understand why is users with admin privileges and clients with admin privileges? They are the same! They both authn/authz with keys and create nodes, etc. ? The only diff bw them is the password attribute? Why do we need separate entity in OSS chef-server for the same job?

Comment: The way I think about it is that `users` are related to persons: they log into the Web UI and they also interact with the Chef Server via `knife` (so they need client keys). `Clients`, on the other hand, are used by machines only, not relating to any particular human. If I was to allow my CI server to deploy new nodes, I'd create a `ci_server` client with such permissions. If a new Chef joins my team, I create a new `user` for him/her. Also, note that the `validator` client is **not** an _admin_. Its sole purpose is to create new client objects on the Chef server for new nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I suspected that the diff bw the client and user is mainly in high level (person/machine) view and not in their functionality.

Answer (score 4):

We did some debugging about this topic. The main idea about `client` and `user` is absolutely to distinguish human and program. How did they do this is what we debuged.

In the db you can see that the `users` can have `admin` group flag, the `clients` can have `admin` and=or `validator` flags.

The `users` can use webUI (with webui `client`) and can use chefAPI.
The `clients` can use **only** chefAPI.

```
opscode_chef=# select username,admin from osc_users;
 username | admin 
----------+-------
 admin    | t
 johnnym  | t
 leki     | t
 nemadmin | f
(4 rows)
                     name                  | admin | validator |                id                
---------------------------------------+-------+-----------+----------------------------------
 chef-validator                        | f     | t         | 0000000000006ab38d5bb2564bd91f5b
 chef-webui                            | t     | f         | 000000000000bd469d802db9a3fc3c88
 statictestXXxd.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.private | f     | f         | 000000000000f106e5461e64a15d0662
 test-validator                        | f     | f         | 000000000000ea638b18e484e034b859
 cica                                  | f     | f         | 00000000000077dd4efbcd39a1fb10d3
(5 rows)

opscode_chef=# select name,environment,last_updated_by from nodes;
                 name                  | environment |         last_updated_by          
---------------------------------------+-------------+----------------------------------
 statictestXXxd.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.private | _default    | 000000000000f106e5461e64a15d0662
 cica_node                             | _default    | 00000000000077dd4efbcd39a1fb10d3
(2 rows)
```

1. `admin` members (both `clients` and `users`) can do **all the commands**
2. `validator` members (**only** `clients`) can do only **node commands**
3. normal members (both `clients` and `users`) can do **client show** and **node commands only if the node is updated by the same client as this request from** (see the table upper)
   (**00000000000077dd4efbcd39a1fb10d3**)

So the client has limited command privileges, also limited scope (only last updated node). The user can have all the privileges but cannot update a node.

I found also this [page](http://docs.opscode.com/auth.html) which helped our research on this topic.